# ExpressJS+TypeScript How to get a request context

Tags: express, typescript, request

TypeScript applies some restrictions. I need pass some variables trough middlewares. At first I redefined requests used interfaces. But it is implicit way. It may invoke some new problems. I like like the application does with the context. It likes a object manager with get() set() methods. I see that request does not have such functionality. I also need request context. Could you help me find clean solution for TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an Interface that extends from express.Requests.

```
export interface IExpressRequest extends express.Request {
  body: {
    email: string,
    dayFrom: string,
    dayTo: string,
    token: string,
    search: {
      email: string
    }
  };
}

export default IExpressRequest;
```